# Method to Reverse a Linked list in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, return-type, singly-linked-list

I am writing a method to reverse a linked list in c++. I'm trying to use `Node*` instead of `void` return type but facing a number of errors.

My method code..

```
  Node* Reverse(Node *head)
   {
     struct node* prev   = NULL;
     struct node* current = head;
     struct node* next;
     while (current != NULL)
      {
        next  = current->next; 
        current->next = prev;  
        prev = current;
        current = next;
      }
        head = prev;
   }
```

The compile time error message i am receiving..

```
    solution.cc: In function 'Node* Reverse(Node*)':
    solution.cc:24:22: error: cannot convert 'Node*' to 'Reverse(Node*)::node*' in initialization
  node* current = head;
                  ^
    solution.cc:28:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Reverse(Node*)::node'
     next  = current->next; 
                    ^
    solution.cc:23:14: error: forward declaration of 'struct Reverse(Node*)::node'
   struct node* prev   = NULL;
          ^
    solution.cc:29:16: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Reverse(Node*)::node'
     current->next = prev;  
            ^
    solution.cc:23:14: error: forward declaration of 'struct Reverse(Node*)::node'
   struct node* prev   = NULL;
          ^
    solution.cc:33:10: error: cannot convert 'Reverse(Node*)::node*' to 'Node*' in assignment
 head = prev;
      ^
    solution.cc:34:1: error: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Werror=return-type]
   }
   ^
    cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: What are the definitions of `node` and `Node`?

Comment: 1 problem is that you must have not completely declared struct node before this method, you might have only put a forward decleration like struct node; Please include the full declaration. Also you say your function will return type o Node* but you do not return anything.

Comment: you don't need to type `struct` everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Node` is not same as `node` and you are missing a `return` statement

```
Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
 struct Node* prev   = NULL;
 struct Node* current = head;
 struct Node* next;
 while (current != NULL)
  {
    next  = current->next; 
    current->next = prev;  
    prev = current;
    current = next;
  }
    head = prev;
   return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//singly linked list

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct stu{

int id;
stu *next = NULL;

};

stu *first = NULL;
stu *last = NULL;

int opt;
int key;


void insert_end();
void display();
void reverse();

int main(){

do{
    
    cout<<"\n0.Exit";
    cout<<"\n1.Insert at end";
    cout<<"\n2.Display";
    cout<<"\n3.Reverse";
    
    cout<<"\n\n\nEnter your choice: ";
    cin>> opt;
    
    switch(opt){
        case 1:{
            insert_end();
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            display();
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            reverse();
            break;
        }
    }   
}
while(opt != 0);
return 0;
}

void insert_end(){

stu *current  = new stu;

cout<<"\n\nEnter the id: ";
cin>>current->id;

if(first == NULL){
    cout<<"\n\nEmpty";
    first = last = current; 
}
else{
    last->next = current;
    last = current;
}
}

void display(){

cout<<"\n";

stu *current  = new stu;
stu *p = first;

if(first == NULL){
    cout<<"\n\nEmpty";
    first = last = current; 
}
else{
    while(p != NULL){
        cout<< p->id<<" ";
        p = p->next;
    }
}

cout<<"\n";

}

void reverse(){

cout<<"\n";

stu *p = first;
stu *p1 = NULL;
stu *k = last;

while(p != k){
    while(p != k){
        p1 = p;
        p = p->next;
    }
    cout<<k->id<<" ";
    k = p1;
    p1 = NULL;
    p = first;
}
cout<<p->id;
cout<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score -1):

It should be Node and not node. plus you must return something as well of Node* type.

```
Node* Reverse(Node *head)
{
  struct Node* prev   = NULL;
  struct Node* current = head;
  struct Node* next = new Node;   //new node;
  while (current != NULL)
  {
    next  = current->next; 
    current->next = prev;  
    prev = current;
    current = next;
  }
    head = prev;

   return head;          //return head as it will return the whole list.

 }
```

Comment: Why the gratuitous memory leak?